# Should I delete `Vertex Buffer Object` after binding it to `Vertex Array Objects`?

Tags: c++, opengl

I created a VBO (Vertex Buffer Object) and VAO (Vertex Array Objects) and did this:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(...);
glVertexAttribPointer(...);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Can I delete the `vbo` after I did this and then draw with the `vao` assuming everything is in order?

I know that the buffers bind to the `vao` so I am assuming I can.

The problem is, if I delete the buffer on my computer (Intel graphics) it works great (everything is displayed correctly), but on my friend computer (AMD) there is nothing displayed.

What could be the problem with that?

(By the way, if I don't delete the buffers the program works both on my computer and on my friend's)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, as per OpenGL 4.5, it is legal to delete it *after you unbind the VAO*.

> ## 2.6.1.2 Name Deletion and Object Deletion
>
> If an object is deleted while it is currently in use by a GL context, its name
>   is immediately marked as unused, and some types of objects are automatically
>   unbound from binding points in the current context, as described in section 5.1.2.
>   **However, the actual underlying object is not deleted until it is no longer in use.**
>   This situation is discussed in more detail in section 5.1.3.
>
> ## 5.1.2 Automatic Unbinding of Deleted Objects
>
> When a buffer, texture, or renderbuffer object is deleted, it is unbound from any
>   bind points it is bound to in the current context, and detached from any attachments
>   of container objects that are bound to the current context, as described for DeleteBuffers, DeleteTextures, and DeleteRenderbuffers. [...] **Attachments to unbound container
>   objects, such as deletion of a buffer attached to a vertex array object which is not
>   bound to the context, are not affected and continue to act as references on the
>   deleted object**, as described in the following section.
>
> ## 5.1.3 Deleted Object and Object Name Lifetimes
>
> When a buffer, texture, sampler, renderbuffer, query, or sync object is deleted, its
>   name immediately becomes invalid (e.g. is marked unused), but the underlying
>   **object will not be deleted until it is no longer in use**.
>
> A buffer, texture, sampler, or renderbuffer object is in use if any of the following conditions are satisfied:
>
> - the object is attached to any container object
> - [...]

So either it's an AMD driver bug, or the situation is not as you describe.

Comment: I just switched to SDL and now everything is drawn BUT when I quit the program I get an exception that says `Access violation` on `wglDeleteContext`

Comment: Previously I used GLFW and nothing was drawn but I didn't get any exception when I quit the program. (The error on SDL is from `atioglxx.dll`)

Comment: @JohnMiz: do you mean on AMD? It's either an AMD bug or a bug in your code that you didn't show. Also I answered based on OpenGL 4.5 spec, as you didn't say which version you use. It might happen that on older versions it should have behaved differently or was left undefined. You are welcome to check the specs yourself, they are freely available and quite human readable.

Comment: As far as I know, it should be backward compatibility @ybungalobill

Comment: @ybungalobill: The behavior you cited (thanks for correcting me, didn't know that), is the same starting from 3.3 Core Profile (D.1.2), so the actually used version shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @JohnMiz: It should be noted that just because something is "legal" doesn't mean it's a good idea. Do not delete objects unless you are *done with them*.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I challenge that. The extra cognitive burden of maintaining the liftetime of those objects that you aren't going to modify anymore is a bad idea. The OpenGL spec already implies the implementation to reference count its objects, so it is a feature we can rely on. Deleting an object thus explicitly stating that "from now on I'm handing it to the driver's responsibility" is something I regularly do and recommend others to do. Of course I personally have the privilege to choose the vendor and OpenGL version I'm working with.

Comment: @NicolBolas What approach is better for real-time graphic engine (for building games mainly ? And what is more optimized in terms of VRAM ?

Comment: @JohnMiz: It's a matter of code style and portability among different implementations. It has nothing to do with VRAM. If you are to build a game engine then you may need to workaround the bugs in different drivers that your users will be using, in such a case you shall not delete the buffers before you deleted the VAO, as Nicol says.

Comment: @ybungalobill: There's also the fact that if you ever want to move to Vulkan, you *cannot* rely on the driver saving you when you do something like deleting objects. In such API, deletion means *gone*, right then and there. Better to train yourself to bear that "cognitive burden" now than to not have it when you need it.